# WSO2 - Remove AD roles from JWT

Tags: jwt, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I need to  remove all roles from JWT which are related to Active Directory. While all internal and local roles from WSO2 IDM should be remain within the JWT.

How to proceed with this ? Any advice highly appreciated.

Please help with this, I will share if more information are required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement a custom JWT generator as mentioned [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/#customizing-the-jwt-generation)?

I assume you are talking about sending custom claims to the backend using the JWT.